# "Caching is not supported by the ItemCountDAOSolr as it is not really needed, Solr is faster!"

Tags: dspace

I am using Dspace. currently I want to update index using the command ./dspace index-lucene-update. but the exception comes "Caching is not supported by the ItemCountDAOSolr as it is not really needed, Solr is faster!" . my question is whether index is built. or how to correct the execption. I have changed some places in dspace.cfg files but can not able to eliminate the error,inform me

Answer (score 1):

You're likely on DSpace 4. This error message has been fixed in DSpace 5.

Nevertheless, I recommend to take a look at the latest definitions of the different indexing operations:
https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Command+Line+Operations

The lucene index is hardly being used, and if you're on DSpace 4 or 5 there are only a few reasons why you want to keep that updated.

You most likely want to run and use ./dspace index-discovery